# .net 6 - Worker Service DI Serilog not injecting itself for ILogger

Tags: dependency-injection, serilog

I have a worker service that I want to use with Serilog

Worker Service has two of my Classes and Interfaces.  Two Classes have CTORs with ILogger

like

```
public class FileConsumerService : IFileConsumerService
    {
        ILogger logger;

        public FileConsumerService(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

... rest of my class
```

I have my Program.cs Main method as follows

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

...

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                 .CreateLogger();

            IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog(logger)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
...
                services.AddSingleton<IFileConsumerService, FileConsumerService>();
                services.AddHostedService<InboundShipmentFileWorker>();
            })
            .Build();

            host.Run();
```

But I'm getting this error

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'FileConsumerService'.

so DI isn't injecting Serilog in for ILogger, it's not even trying....  I have UseSerilog(logger) as the first line in the host builder, but I'm missing something, somewhere...

Have another application, where this seems to be working, with the same setup.. Create logger from config, .UseSerilog(logger) in the host builder..... works perfectly.  this one, doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me here was that my helper classes were constructed with just ILogger, instead of ILogger with their specific types.